# How to Get Value from Index controller to Collection in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to get the value from Index controller.

Controller\Adminhtml\Orders\Index.php :

```
  public function execute()
  { 
    $storeid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('storeid');
    $this->settings->setStoreid($storeid);
   }
```

Model\Settings.php

```
public function setStoreid($storeid)
{
    $this->storeid = $storeid;
}

public function getStoreid()
{
    return $this->storeid;
}
```

Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection.php :

```
   public function _renderFiltersBefore{       
      $storeid = $this->getStoreId();

     // var_dump($storeid)
      // $storeid = 5

      $this->getSelect()->where('store_id = ?', $storeid);
   }
```

I want to pass the storeid to the query Collection. I can able to set the storeid from Index class and can able to get the storeid in Collection class. But it doesnt passing to the collection.
If I set the value directly to storeid, ie. $storeid = 5, then collection works fine.  Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use registry

```
/**
  * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
  */

 protected $_registry;

 /**
 * ...
 * ...
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
 */
public function __construct(
    ...,
    ...,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    ...
) {
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    ...
    ...
}

 /**
 * Setting custom variable in registry to be used
 *
 */

public function setCustomVariable()
{
     $this->registry->register('custom_var', 'Added Value');
}

/**
 * Retrieving custom variable from registry
 * @return string
 */
public function getCustomVariable()
{
     return $this->registry->registry('custom_var');
}
```